# Check if numbers / values are in ascending order in input (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `n` input-fields for values in my form. I need to check if the values are in ascending order, otherwiese it should yield an error.

Since the numbers can  be inserted in many ways, I made a small "cleanup" beforehand.

Possible inputs are:

```
100.000
100000
100000,00
100.000,00
```

All inputs are valid and all are *the same*. My current JS looks like this:

The ID's in my input-fields follow this pattern: `staff_u1, staff_u2, ...`

```
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (($("#staff_u"+(i+1)).length > 0 && !$("#staff_u"+(i+1)).val() != NaN) && parseFloat($("#staff_u"+i).val().replace(',','.').replace(' ','')) < parseFloat($("#staff_u"+(i+1)).val().replace(',','.').replace(' ',''))) {
        console.log("Not in ascending order");
    }
}
```

From the beginning, there are **3** input-fields given. I think that not having a value in the fields also yields an unwanted behaviour.

To give an example what is valid and what not:

```
1. --> 200000,00
2. --> 300000,00
3. --> 250000     
================
not valid, since the 2nd value is > 3rd

1. --> 15000
2. --> 25000
3. --> 35000
================
valid

1. --> 7.500,00
2. --> 12000
3. --> 15.000
4. --> '' (empty input, doesn't mean 0, should not be taken into the comparison)
================
valid, ascending, even though differently formatted
```

This is the default mask, which the user is presented with, even though there are no values prefilled. Only the €-values are important to compare. I think my current solution crashes, since the 3rd value is empty.

[image: Default mask]

Comment: Copy into an array, sort and compare would seem the easiest way.

Comment: please don't mix DOM access code i.e. `$("#staff_u"+(i+1)).val()` with business logic.   Get the values out of your fields first, and only _then_ perform the comparisons you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a nested approach by filtering the array, getting numbers an check each value with its predecessor.

```js
function getNumber(s) {
    return +s.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.');
}

function check(array) {
    return array
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(getNumber)
        .every((v, i, a) => !i || a[i - 1] < v);
}

var arrays = [
        ['100.000', '80.000', '90.000'],      // false
        ['200000,00', '300000,00', '250000'], // false
        ['15000', '25000', '35000'],          // true
        ['7.500,00', '12000', '15.000', '']   // true
    ];

console.log(arrays.map(check));
```

Comment: I thought about that as well, but only checking against the predecessor is wrong, for example in this case: 100.000, 80.000. 90.000, (it would be greater than the 2nd. element, but not as the 1st, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Shouldn't `+s.replace(/\./, '')` also replace 'dot' globally? `+s.replace(/\./g, '')` in case number is `100.000.000`

Comment: @NitishNarang, right, it should. thanks for the hint.